# Spring ThreadPoolTaskExecutor response time increases a lot

Tags: java, spring, executor

I have configured Spring ThreadPoolTaskExecutor, trying to have in mind the average load of 1,1k rpm.

```
  @Qualifier("executor")
  public Executor asyncExecutor() {

    this.threadPoolTaskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(800);
    this.threadPoolTaskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(900);
    this.threadPoolTaskExecutor.initialize();
    ..
  }

  //sender method
  @Async("executor")
  @Override
  public void sendObject (ObjectFormatter object) {

    executor.execute(() -> {
      try {
        items.forEach(item -> item.send(object));
    });
```

However, after a period of time the POST request for which the async configurations are made suddenly increases up to 5 hours (from the average ms period). More so, usually after those spikes the app stops sending the POST requests.

Response time picture:

[image: Response time picture]

What could be the cause of it?
I have tried to play around with the core and max pool sizes, but eventually sooner or later the behaviors happens again.

Comment: a "thumb rule" sets core-pool-size to number-of-processors ... when you say 1k rpm (1 minute is 60,000 milliseconds) ..and avg job 1-10ms ... 8 (real) threads can do the job easily.. .. the symptoms you describe, sound like a big memory leak/exhaustion

Comment: Please attach the picture correctly

Comment: HI, @xerx593, thank you for the input.
Would threadPoolTaskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(8) and threadPoolTaskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(900) do the trick?